# Upload multiple sheet Excel into internal table

Tags: excel, abap, sap-erp

I have Excel file and there are more than one worksheets (multiple worksheets), so I need to upload all data from this worksheets. This function 'TEXT_CONVERT_XLS_TO_SAP' is not suitable because upload only data from active worksheet (only one worksheet).

Answer (score 1):

I found these. Normally the way this works is that you provide code what you've tried so far and where problems occured. Asking for solutions is not the thing you get here, but from google:

1. https://archive.sap.com/discussions/thread/594226 --> sample coding in report
2. https://archive.sap.com/discussions/thread/3191410 --> they even    provide an sample report

Comment: **(1)** Example based on OLE (frontend only) **(2)** Example based on classes "Desktop Office Integration" (technology based on OLE + has some stuff at the SAP GUI to "accelerate" OLE - frontend only - note that TEXT_CONVERT_XLS_TO_SAP also uses DOI but SAP has simply limited its features to only one worksheet)

Answer (score 0):

```
data: l_t_data   type w3mimetabtype,
      l_t_files  type filetable,
      l_rc       type i.

cl_gui_frontend_services=>file_open_dialog(
  exporting
    file_filter = '*.xlsx'
    default_filename = '*.xlsx'
  changing
    file_table = l_t_files
    rc = l_rc
).
check l_t_files[] is not initial.

cl_gui_frontend_services=>gui_upload(
  exporting
    filename = conv string( l_t_files[ 1 ]-filename )
    filetype = 'BIN'
  importing
    filelength = data(l_length)
  changing
    data_tab = l_t_data
).

try.
   data(l_r_xls) = new cl_fdt_xl_spreadsheet(
     document_name = conv string( l_t_files[ 1 ]-filename )
     xdocument = cl_fxs_converter=>w3mimetab_to_xstring( iv_w3mimetab = l_t_data iv_length = l_length )
   ).
catch cx_fdt_excel_core.
  assert 1 = 2.
endtry.

l_r_xls->if_fdt_doc_spreadsheet~get_worksheet_names( importing worksheet_names = data(l_t_worksheets) ).
```

Answer (score -2):

can u put all data in one sheet ?

you can allways make a macro or so, and join all data from the sheets into one, and then use the TEXT_CONVERT_XLS_TO_SAP that you comment.

good luck

Comment: no I can't put all data in one sheet - The condition is that the worksheets will be 14 pieces!